# Integer promotions in C programming

Tags: c

In the code below which statements have integer promotions?

```
unchar a;
unchar b;
short c;
a = 0xFE;
b = 0xFE;
c = a+b;
int d = a==b
```

I got the question like this in a question series. How to answer it.

Moreover,Some data types like char , short int take less number of bytes than int, these data types are automatically promoted to int or unsigned int when an operation is performed on them. This is called integer promotion. For example no arithmetic calculation happens on smaller types like char, short and enum.

Comment: "smaller types like ... enum." The `enum` type is implementation defined but is quite often `int` or `unsigned int`. What is the question, and the source of confusion?

Comment: Can we conside a = 0xFE as integer promotion ?

Comment: No, it is an integer *conversion*, as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_conversions). The `0xFE` is already an `int` type and does not need to be promoted.

Comment: OK, so in this question we have only first three statements that have integer promotions ?

Comment: None of the first three statements have integer promotions. They are variable type definitions.

Comment: Okk, I got it, and what about c = a+b.   and  int d = a==b

Comment: What do *you* think will happen when you add two values of that type?

Comment: Got it ,I understood the concept thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which statements have integer promotions.

> `unchar a;`
> `unchar b;`
> `short c;`

These appear to be declarations, and possibly `unchar` is an alias for `unsigned char`. There are no expressions in them, so there are no integer promotions.

> `a = 0xFE;`

`0xFE` is an unsuffixed hexadecimal constant whose value, 254, must fit in an `int`. Per C 2018 6.4.4.1 5, its type is `int`. `a` is an lvalue. As the left operand of an assignment, it is left as an lvalue and not converted to a value.

Per C 2018 6.5.16 2, the right operand is converted to the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion, hence `unsigned char`. The integer promotions are not performed.

> `b = 0xFE;`

This is the same as above.

> `c = a+b;`

For the binary `+` operator on arithmetic operands, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed, per c 2018 6.5.6 5. For integer operations, the usual arithmetic conversions include the integer promotions. Thus the integer promotions are performed on `a` and on `b`.

Except in esoteric C implementations, `int` can represent all the values of `unsigned char`. In this case, the integer promotions convert `unsigned char` to `int`. So they convert each of `a` and `b` to `int`.

Then `+` produces an `int` result, and, since it is the right operand of assignment, it is converted to the type `c` would have after lvalue conversion, `short`. There are no further integer promotions.

> `int d = a==b`

This is similar to above. For arithmetic operands of `==`, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed, per C 2018 6.5.9 4. These include the integer promotions on `a` and on `b`. There are no other integer promotions in this.